# I want to disable every Sunday AND specify DateFormat datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker on my website. Now I want to disable every sunday and also I will specify the dateformat.

When I try it separate it works, but when I mixed it up it fails. I'am afraid here is something wrong. I test it here and all works, but not on my site: http://jsfiddle.net/zXFGN/26/

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
minDate: -0, 
maxDate: "+24M", 
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" 
});
});

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: noSunday
});

function noSunday(date){ 
      var day = date.getDay(); 
                  return [(day > 0), '']; 
  }; 
</script>
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" value="" size="10" placeholder="dd- mm-yyyy">
```

I tried many things, but nothing helps. So please I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Hajee

Comment: Have you checked browser console for any script errors? Are you **sure** your code is identical in your website compared to your JsFiddle?

Comment: no script errors and I paste it immedetialy in my source code...

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle **doesn't** work, since the format of the date selected isn't the format specified in your code. The problem is that you're calling `.datepicker({/*options*/})` twice, and the second call overrides the options you've set in the first call. Specify all of the options in a single call when initialising the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: -0, 
    maxDate: "+24M", 
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    beforeShowDay: noSunday
  });
});
```

If you absolutely need to update an option *after* the datepicker has been initialized, then you need to use the `option` method, like so:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", noSunday);
```

Or, if you want to update more than one at the same time, pass an object of updated options like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("option", {
    beforeShowDay: noSunday
});
```

---

There's a second point of confusion caused by the jsFiddle. You have it set to run onDomReady which means that jsFiddle creates a DOM ready callback to execute your code for you. This isn't how code in a regular webpage works; you need to put **all** code that relies on the DOM being ready inside jQuery's DOM ready handler, like you have with the first call to `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({})` but not the second.